# Facebook Posting a url to page

Tags: facebook

I use below code to post an url to facebook page as a admin but if i post an message,it is posting but it is not posting photos and url.

```
 $args = array(
            'access_token'  => token,
            'message'       => $url
        );

        $wall = $facebook->api("/".$pid."/feed","post",$args);
```

Is there any other function that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

- 'caption'
- 'link'
- 'picture'

variables to your array to show a picture with a caption and a link to a url.

Comment: :Photo got posted on my wall but when i clicked on photo,it took to my web server file location.It should not go there,is there any other solution to upload on album.